# Switch to a different Mongo database from withing the docker exec command

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running a mongoDB instance from within a docker container.  I am trying to switch to issue commands using docker exec and the --eval options.  What I am trying to accomplish is this:

1. Switch to my database
2. Authenticate into the database
3. Drop a collection

The command I am running to do this is as follows:

```
docker exec -it mongo_instance mongo ir --eval "db.adminCommand('use db1'); db.auth("dbuser","dbpassword"); db.storage.drop()"
```

When I run this command, it always fails saying:

```
ReferenceError: dbuser is not defined :
```

Which I know it is.  That user is located in the db1 database and I just need to switch to that database in order for the authentication to work.

If I run the following from inside the mongo shell, it works:

```
use ir
db.auth("dbuser","dbpassword")
db.storage.drop()
```

Any ideas how I can get around this or get this done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [differences between interactive and scripted `mongo` shell interaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo). In particular, syntax like `use db` only works in an interactive session. You can also use `mongo` command-line options to simplify the JavaScript to eval and avoid having passwords in your shell history.

Assuming your authentication database name is `ir` and the collection to drop is `db1.storage` , a suggested command line to use would be:

> docker exec -it mongo_instance mongo -u dbuser -p --authenticationDatabase ir --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db1').storage.drop()"

A few comments on this:

- The [`db.getSiblingDB()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/)  helper is the scripting equivalent for the interactive `use <db>` syntax. You could also specify the dbname to use as part of the `mongo` command line (eg: `mongo -u dbuser -p db1 ...`), but `db.getSiblingDB('db1')` may still be preferable as an extra sanity check that you are dropping a collection from the expected database.
- If the collection you are dropping is also in the same database as your admin credentials, a shorter option for the `mongo` command line would be: `mongo -u dbuser -p ir --eval "db.storage.drop()"`. The shell uses the `dbname`  you are connecting to as the default auth database.
- There is also a [`db.getCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) helper which is useful if you want to be more intentional about the collection name (or if the collection name clashes with built-in methods or isn't valid in JavaScript). An equivalent to the example above would be `db.getSiblingDB('db1').getCollection('storage').drop()`.
- Using `-p` (aka `--password`) without providing a password argument will prompt you for the password so it won't be accidentally saved in your shell history. Alternatively you could use `-p dbpassword` if you aren't fussed about the password being saved.